# Почему не открывается окно?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


}
class myFrame extends JFrame {


    public myFrame() {
        myPanel ramka = new myPanel();

        setSize (640, 480);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }
    class myPanel extends JPanel {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Метод psvm пустой...

Answer (score 0):

У Вас пустой метод `main`, так должно работать:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myFrame myFrame = new myFrame();
}
static class myFrame extends JFrame {

    public myFrame() {
        myPanel ramka = new myPanel();
        setSize (640, 480);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    class myPanel extends JPanel {
    }
}
```